# How to align the text in front of images

Tags: css

This is my code:

```css
.left-ul {
  margin-left: 10px!important;
  display: inline-block!important;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 350px;
}

.iconic {
  padding: 2%!important;
  color: #111!important;
  font-size: 16px!important;
}

li {
  display: list-item;
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}
```

```html
<div id="news">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <img src="images/prof.jpg" style="width:90%;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 price-grid feature-list">
        <legend>
          <h2>Highlights of the Program</h2>
        </legend>
        <ul class="left-ul">
          <img src="images/thumb.png" style="width:55px; height:55px;">
          <li class="iconic">Industry experts as faculty and guest lecturers</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to show text:

> Industry experts as faculty and guest lecturers

in front of the image and my text is coming below the images.

I'm not able to align the text in front of images. Both should be face to face.
I have tried using text-align property but that did not work.

If you require more files please let me know.

Comment: You should consider using `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` for positioning text under images.

Comment: @Andrew i do not want to position  text under images but i want to position if fron of image or straight face to face closee to each other

Comment: You have an error in your HTML: the <img> is outside the <li>. Put it inside the <li>, after the text. By the way, the <legend> is misplaced too, but I don't think that's too big a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `float: right;` to the image:

```css
.left-ul {
  margin-left: 10px!important;
  display: inline-block!important;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 350px;
}

.iconic {
  padding: 2%!important;
  color: #111!important;
  font-size: 16px!important;
}
.left-ul > img {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="news">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <img src="images/prof.jpg" style="width:90%;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 price-grid feature-list">
        <legend>
          <h2>Highlights of the Program</h2>
        </legend>
        <ul class="left-ul">
          <img src="images/thumb.png" style="width:55px; height:55px;">
          <li class="iconic">Industry experts as faculty and guest lecturers</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```